# How can i substitute the characters of a string with two keys (one for each character)?

Tags: java, security, encryption, substitution

I'm writing a program that performs the polyalphabetic cipher. This works by :

1- taking two (26 characters) strings called 'keys', let's call them k1 and k2

Ex:

k1 = "asdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiop";
k2 = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";

2- takes any string from the user (word or sentence), let's call it "PT" for plaintext

Ex:
PT = "Hello";

3- replace each character in PT with k1 & k2. the first character using k1, second character using k2, the third character back to k1 and so on... To produce "CT" for ciphertext

Ex:
The ciphertext for "hello" should be: ktcsn

H -> k (because h is the 8th character in the alphabet and the 8th alphabet in k1)

E -> t (because e is the 5th character in the alphabet and the 5th alphabet in k2)

L -> c (because l is the 12th character in the alphabet and the 12th alphabet in k1)

L -> s (because l is the 12th character in the alphabet and the 12th alphabet in k2)

O -> n (because o is the 15th character in the alphabet and the 15th alphabet in k1)

This is what I've written so far:

```
    String alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    for (int i = 0; i < PT.length(); i++)
        {
            int pos = alpha.indexOf(PT.charAt(i));
             PT.replace(PT.charAt(pos), k1.charAt(i));
             int k2Pos = i++;
             PT.replace(PT.charAt(pos+1), k2.charAt(k2Pos));
    }
        return PT;
```

but I get a "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 7 out of bounds for length 5".

Thank you, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It is likely you need to change for loop to iterate for length()-1 so from:

```
for (int i = 0; i < PT.length(); i++)
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < PT.length()-1; i++)
```

That is just a first problem though, you are also jumping ahead one iteration with

```
int k2Pos = i++;
```

so getting out of bounds as trying to take character at position in a String that does not exist as PT is shorter
And third problem I see is

```
PT.replace(PT.charAt(pos), k1.charAt(i));
```

is trying to use wrong character from k1, should be

```
k1.charAt(pos)
```

In cases like this, going step by step in debug mode is very helpful as you can see which iteration you are on when exception is thrown, which line is causing it etc.